# Filtering is not working for child grid in kendo-ui hierarchical grid with Razor MVC

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement filtering on child grid in kendo-ui hierarchical grid in  MVC but it's giving error.

HTML Code Sample :

```
.Columns(col =>
            {
                col.Bound(o => o.Id).Hidden(true);               
                col.Bound(o => o.Column1).Width(100).ClientTemplate("\\#= BuildLink(data,'1') \\#");
                col.Bound(o => o.Column2).Width(100).ClientTemplate("\\#= BuildLink(data,'2') \\#");
                col.Bound(o => o.Column3).Width(100).ClientTemplate("\\#= BuildLink(data,'3') \\#");
                col.Bound(o => o.YTDSailedCalls).Width(100).ClientTemplate("\\#= BuildLink(data,'4') \\#");               
            })
                      .Sortable().Scrollable().Filterable()
                        .Pageable(pageable => pageable.Refresh(true)
                        .PageSizes(new int[5] { 20, 40, 80, 100, 200 })
                        .ButtonCount(5))
```

but its giving error in browser console and nothing get displayed.

Please reply as soon as possible if anyone face this issue or have solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this-

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.OrderViewModel>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.OrderID).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false))).Width(225);
    columns.Bound(p => p.ShipName).Width(500).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
    columns.Bound(p => p.Freight).Width(255).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("gte")));
    columns.Bound(p => p.OrderDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .ServerOperation(true)
    .Read(read => read.Action("Orders_Read", "Grid"))
 )
```

)

For more assistance refer this link-

[Kendo Grid filter](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/filter-row)